# how to use the cyborg OnBootCompletedListener?

Tags: android, cyborg

So I've added the the BootStarterReceiver receiver in the manifest, 
I've added the OnBootCompletedListener implementation in the module file.
(is this the correct practice btw? in the module class)

Now how do I start the application?
what do I implement in the OnBootCompleted method?

There's the

```
cyborg.startActivity()
```

but I don't know how to use the Intent here as I don't have any activities, only controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to add the *BootStarterReceiver* to the manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.nu.art.cyborg.common.utils.BootStarterReceiver">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Or just enable the BootStarterReceiver if you are using the latest(0.8.11 +) Cyborg version:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.nu.art.cyborg.common.utils.BootStarterReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"/>
```

You'd also need to add the respective permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

One this setup is done, choose your boot handling module and implement the **OnBootCompletedListener**, in the *onBootCompleted* method perform your code there.

As for staring a new activity at that point... I am not sure how your users will respond to that, but you can call cyborg.startActivity(), with an intent that will launch Cyborg's default ApplicationLauncher, and **add the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**.

```
public void onBootCompleted() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ApplicationLauncher.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    cyborg.startActivity(intent);
}
```